# how can move entire div with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 type div and I want change the location of one of them based on which button is clicked with JavaScript.

1. I want when user click on button with `answer-btn` ID. The answer-form div move it to section `<!--move here section-->`.
2. If the answer-form shows and user click on the same answer-btn the answer-form is hidden.
3. If user clicks on another answer-btn the answer-form remove form the current location and move to the new `<!--move here section-->` section.

```js
function showHideAsnwerForm() {
  var answerForm = document.getElementById("answer-form");

  // Check if the element has the "my-class" class
  if (answerForm.classList.contains("d-none")) {
    var nearestComment = answerForm.closest("#comment");

    nearestComment.appendChild(answerForm);
    answerForm.classList.remove("d-none");
  } else {
    answerForm.classList.add("d-none");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="answer-form" class="border border-secondary  text-right  m-2 d-none " style="background-color:gainsboro;">
  <p class="p-2">لطفا پاسخ خود را بنویسید</p>

  <form asp-action="CreateComment" asp-controller="CategoryItem" class="was-validated w-100  p-2 " method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="BookFK" value="" name="BookFK" required>

    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control " aria-label="With textarea" rows="5" id="Text" name="Text" required></textarea>
      <div class="valid-feedback">تایید شد</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">لطفا این بخش را پر کنید.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mt-1 d-inline-block w-100 ">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-end"> ثبت پاسخ   </button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger float-start"> لغو   </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="  border-dark border-2 border-end mt-1 mb-1 me-2" id="comment">
  <div>
    <img id="imgMain" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class=" img-thumbnail rounded-circle rounded-3" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
    <b>نام کاربری</b> تاریخ: 1345/23/2
  </div>

  <div class="pe-1">
    پاسخ 8
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
    <button onclick="showHideAsnwerForm()" id="aswer-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-2">#answer-btn</button>
  </div>

  <!--move here section-->
</div>
```

Comment: I made an attempt to make your post more clear and readable. Please become familiar with the editor so you can format your content better. Revise as needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```js
// Get the answer buttons and answer form
var answerButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('answer-btn');
var answerForm = document.getElementById('answer-form');

// Add click event listeners to the answer buttons
for (var i = 0; i < answerButtons.length; i++) {
  answerButtons[i].addEventListener('click', toggleAnswerForm);
}

// Toggle the answer form visibility and move it to the new section
function toggleAnswerForm() {
  if (answerForm.style.display === 'block') {
    // Hide the answer form
    answerForm.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    // Move the answer form to the new section
    var currentSection = document.querySelector('section');
    currentSection.appendChild(answerForm);
    answerForm.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="answer-btn">Button 1</button>
<button class="answer-btn">Button 2</button>

<div id="answer-form" style="display: none;">Answer Form</div>

<section><!--move here section--></section>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).